# Get string ending with zero or more digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query which returns string ending with zero or more digits.

For example, I have strings 'amit', 'amityy', 'amit001'. I want to only return 'amit' and 'amit001'.

I tried `LIKE 'amit%'`, but not get success.

Comment: How can a string not end with zero or more digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checks if the string starts with `amit` and that there are only numbers after `amit`:

```
LIKE 'amit%' AND NOT LIKE 'amit%[^0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server Transact-SQL `like` doesn't have an option for zero or more of something you have to do it in two steps. One way would be to check for equals and then check if it has numbers after.

`(afield = 'amit' OR afield like 'amit%[0-9]')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return only amit and amit001 values, this is your correct query predicate:

where tfield = 'amit' or tfield = 'amit001'

But if you want to retunr amit and amit with some numeric value:

where tfield = 'amit' or tfield like 'amit%[^0-9]%'